# OpenOffice Base Report that takes user input

Tags: database, ms-access, openoffice.org

I'm working on a LOT of VBA code that generates reports from Excel.

I reckon it's a really stupid idea to use Excel and VBA to run "queries" on an worksheet so I'd like to do it in a database environment.

I successfully ported the required table and data into OpenOffice base. The problem now is that I need to run a report that takes in user input for example in a pizza database:

"Show me total use of ham on a weekly basis and consolidate that on a month by month basis."

Where "ham" would be an ingredient that the user could change for say, "pepperoni".

How do I create a report that takes user input? Do I need to do it with a subform? Can I connect a form to a report?

Comment: Does your installation/license for MS Office include Access? If so, I would really recommend using that instead of Base. Last time I looked at it, about half a year ago, Base was really really limited in it's capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to drop-lists, named ranges, and advanced functions like sumproduct(), you might be able to do everything you need in Excel, possibly without any VBA (It's more powerful than most people realize).  Can you give us some more examples?